# Date plus x days in the SUMIF formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I got the exact column with the certain date in sumif formula as a condition in this formula.
I need to add 14 days to each of the date in the column. I know I can make a additional column with `‘date + 14 days’` and add this column to the formula to count it from this additional column, but I need it directly in the formula without using the additional column.

Can anybody help please? I tried to create my own function in Google Apps Script but it does not work. It is here:

```
function plusDni(stlpec_ceny, stlpec_datumy, datum_od, datum_do, dni) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= stlpec_ceny.length; i++) {
      datum_od = new Date(datum_od);
      datum_do = new Date(datum_do);
      stlpec_datumy[i] = new Date(stlpec_datumy[i]) + dni;
      if((stlpec_datumy[i] != undefined || stlpec_datumy[i] != null) 
       && 
       (stlpec_datumy[i].getTime() > datum_od.getTime() && stlpec_datumy[i].getTime() < datum_do.getTime())) {
     sum = sum + Number(stlpec_ceny[i]);
    }

   
  }
  return sum;
}
```

`plusDni()` arguments description:

```
stlpec_datumy - dates column
stlpec_ceny  - prices column
datum_od - date from 
datum_do - date to 
dni - days (integer) to add every row in dates column
```

Comment: Please, do not add extra info as comment. Edit yuour original question and add it there.

Comment: Are you trying to add 14 days to a date object and get the new date object using sheets functions? or Apps Script?